# can't address JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a locally saved JSON file in which I have a bunch of objects/strings. I have trouble addressing each value. The beginning looks like this:

```
{
  "result":{
    "heroes":[
      {
        "name":"npc_dota_hero_antimage",
        "id":1,
         "localized_name":"Anti-Mage"
      },
      {
        "name":"npc_dota_hero_axe",
        "id":2,
        "localized_name":"Axe"
      },
      ...
```

after including it in my JS I attempt to console log `console.log(heroes.result[0].heroes[0].name)`.

I know it's a dumb question but I can't figure it out right now.This is my markup:

```
const endpoint = './heroes.json'

let heroes = []

fetch(endpoint)
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    .then(data => heroes.push(data))

console.log(heroes)
```

Comment: try `heroes.result.heroes[0].name`

Comment: results isn't an array, its an object.

Comment: is your object pointed to a variable `heroes`?

Comment: You're accesing as array the object `result`, try this: `console.log(heroes.result.heroes[0].name)`

Comment: my apologies, i should have clarified what i have so far: const endpoint = 
    './heroes.json'

    let heroes = []

    fetch(endpoint)
     .then(blob => blob.json())
            .then(data => heroes.push(data))

    console.log(heroes.result.heroes[0].name)

Answer (score 0):

Result is an object and not an array. You need to remove the index from that

```
heroes.result.heroes[0].name
```

```js
var heroes={
  "result":{
    "heroes":[
      {
        "name":"npc_dota_hero_antimage",
        "id":1,
         "localized_name":"Anti-Mage"
      },
      {
        "name":"npc_dota_hero_axe",
        "id":2,
        "localized_name":"Axe"
      }]
      }
}

console.log(heroes.result.heroes[0].name)
```

Comment: What are you getting for `console.log(heroes)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.` for object properties as `result` is object you need to use . instead of `[]`

```js
var heroes={
  "result":{
    "heroes":[
      {
        "name":"npc_dota_hero_antimage",
        "id":1,
         "localized_name":"Anti-Mage"
      },
      {
        "name":"npc_dota_hero_axe",
        "id":2,
        "localized_name":"Axe"
      }]
      }
}

console.log(heroes.result.heroes[0].name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`heroes.result.heroes[0].name`
```

That should do. Bear in mind that result is a property of the first object 'heroes' as well as the second 'heroes' is a property of the object 'result'.

The key of the second 'heroes', however, is an array. Therefore you use an index to access the first element in the array: `heroes[0]`.

Third, `heroes[0]` contains an object so we are accessing its property 'name', therefore `.name`.